# Wrong Geography ID with these Latitude and Longitude

Tags: google-maps, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following Latitude and Longitude

Latitude  -45.8638285918367 
Longitude -67.4942747346939

When input these coordinates to Google Maps is giving the correct "place".

I tried the following:

```
SELECT geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(-67.4942747346939 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(-45.8638285918367 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)

SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST(-67.4942747346939 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(-45.8638285918367 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)

SELECT geography::Point(-45.8638285918367, -67.4942747346939, 4326)

SELECT geography::Parse('POINT(' + CAST(-45.8638285918367 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(-67.4942747346939 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')')
```

To no avail if I put the Geography in my SQL when the google maps have loaded the marker will point to a lake near finland where in fact is in the south of Argentina.

What Im doing wrong? which one is the correct way to get the geography from these two Lat,Long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer, The correct spatial reference ID was 4236